# Tic Tac Toe resetting the board after the 3rd move

Tags: c

So everything works fine till the 4th move. It then resets the board and puts and X in the first box. What's wrong with it? Also I would prefer if I would be guided to the answer, not just given it, it's for the learning. I've also tried finding the answer without any help by cutting one part and checking what effect it does. (Don't know how to use the debugger cause it always gives out, filename has no debugging information).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int clear(void);
int displayboard(void);
int initialize(void);
int startgame(void);
int checkwin(char);
int canwin(void);
int getmove(void);
int makemove(void);
int canblock(void);
char board[3][3];
int main()
{   
    int menuchoice;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("            |\\  /| | |    /\\   |\\  |\n");
        printf("            | \\/ | | |   /--\\  | \\ |\n");
        printf("            |    | | |_ /    \\ |  \\|\n");
        printf("              Tic-tac-toe Version 1 \n\n");
        printf("                  [Main Menu]\n");
        printf("                 1 - Start game\n");
        printf("                 2 - Exit game\n");
        scanf("%d",&menuchoice);
        if(menuchoice==1)
        {
            clear();
            startgame();
        }
        else if(menuchoice==2)
        {
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
    }
}
/* Prints newlines to refresh the page */
int clear(void)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<25;i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
/* Makes the board blank */
int initialize(void)
{
    int numrow,numcol;
    numrow=0;
    numcol=0;
    while(numrow<3)
    {   
        while(numcol<3)
        {   
            board[numrow][numcol]=' ';
            numcol++;
        }
        numcol=0;
        numrow++;
    }
    return 0;
}
/* Prints the board */
int displayboard(void)
{
    printf("                 1    2    3\n\n\n");
    printf("              1   %c | %c | %c \n",board[0][0],board[0][1],board[0][2]);
    printf("                ------------- \n");
    printf("              2   %c | %c | %c  \n",board[1][0],board[1][1],board[1][2]);
    printf("                ------------- \n");
    printf("              3   %c | %c | %c  \n",board[2][0],board[2][1],board[2][2]);
    return 0;
}
/* Function that controls the game*/
int startgame(void)
{

    int movecount;
    while(1)
    {
        movecount=0;
        initialize();   
        displayboard();
        board[1][1]='X';
        clear();
        displayboard();
        getmove();
        makemove();
        movecount=3;
        while(1)
        {
            clear();
            displayboard();
            getmove();
            /* I believe the problem starts here */
            if(checkwin('O')==1)
            {
                printf("\n\t\t\tYou WIN!!!!");
                /*just to test*/
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }
            movecount++;
            canwin(); /* Checks if it can make winning move */
            if(canblock()==0) /*if a move to block has not been made*/
            {
                makemove();
                movecount++;
            }
            else if(canblock()==1) /*if a move to block has been made*/
            {
                movecount++;
            }
            if(checkwin('X')==1)
            {
                printf("\n\t\t\tYou LOSE!!!");
                /* just to test */
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }
            if(movecount==9)
            {
                printf("                Its a DRAW!!!");
                /*Just to test */
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }
        }
    }
}
/* Function to check win */
int checkwin(char ltr)
{
    int rownumber,colnumber;
    for(rownumber=0;rownumber<3;rownumber++)
    {
        if(board[rownumber][0]==ltr && board[rownumber][1]==ltr && board[rownumber][2]==ltr)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    for(colnumber=0;colnumber<3;colnumber++)
    {
        if(board[0][colnumber]==ltr && board[1][colnumber]==ltr && board[2][colnumber]==1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if(board[0][0]==ltr && board[1][1]==ltr && board[2][2]==ltr)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(board[0][2]==ltr && board[1][1]==ltr && board[2][0]==ltr)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
/* Function to get move */
int getmove(void)
{
    int colnumber,rownumber;
    printf("\n\t\t\tWhat row do you want to put your move?\n");
    scanf("%d",&rownumber);
    printf("\n\t\t\tWhat column do you want to put your move?\n");
    scanf("%d",&colnumber);
    board[rownumber-1][colnumber-1]='O';
    return 0;
}
/* Function to makemove */
int makemove(void)
{
    if(board[0][0]==' ')
    {
        board[0][0]='X';
        return 0;
    }
    else if(board[0][2]==' ')
    {
        board[0][2]='X';
        return 0;
    }
    else if(board[2][0]==' ')
    {
        board[2][0]='X';
        return 0;
    }
    else if(board[2][2]==' ')
    {
        board[2][2]='X';
        return 0;
    }
    else if(board[0][1]==' ')
    {
        board[0][1]=='X';
        return 0;
    }
    else if(board[1][0]==' ')
    {
        board[1][0]='X';
        return 0;
    }
    else if(board[1][2]==' ')
    {
        board[1][2]='X';
        return 0;
    }
    else if(board[2][1]==' ')
    {
        board[2][1]='X';
        return 0;
    }
}
/* Function to make winning move */
int canwin(void)
{
    int rownumber,colnumber;
    for(rownumber=0;rownumber<3;rownumber++)
    {
        for(colnumber=0;colnumber<3;colnumber++)
        {
            board[rownumber][colnumber]='X';
            if(checkwin('X')==1)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            board[rownumber][colnumber]=' ';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
/* Function to block winning move */
int canblock(void)
{
    int rownumber,colnumber;
    for(rownumber=0;rownumber<3;rownumber++)
    {
        for(colnumber=0;colnumber<3;colnumber++)
        {
            board[rownumber][colnumber]='O';
            if(checkwin('O')==1)
            {
                board[rownumber][colnumber]='X';
                return 1;
            }
            else if(checkwin('O')==0)
            {
                board[rownumber][colnumber]=' ';
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To use your debugger, you need to compile your program with the appropriate compiler option (which for example is `-g` for gcc).

Comment: Also, if using gcc, compile with `-Wall`, which warns for writing code which almost always is some kind of error, e.g. gcc tells me that your function `makemove` doesn't return any value if one of your `if`s doesn't trigger. It also told me, that your statement `board[0][1]=='X';` has no effect, you probably meant to write `board[0][1]='X';` here.

Comment: any idea for Pelles C ide?, also in the makemove, its impossible not to trigger any if or else if statements cause if all the blocks are taken the game will end as a draw because the movecount will be =9, oh i typed == instead of = for that one. FIXED. but same issue goes on and it doesnt seem to be the one causing the main problem

Comment: No idea about Pelles C, they have their own compiler afaik. About `makemove`: If it always returns 1 and you don't use the return value, why don't declare `makemove` as `void makemove(void)`?

Comment: Quick google about "Pelles C debugging" got me this [forum thread](http://forum.pellesc.de/index.php?topic=4194.0), also the help files seem to contain lots of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you got a problem in your `canwin()` function, as I understand it, you want the A.I. to test if it can make a winning move. But looking at the function

```
int canwin(void)
{
    int rownumber,colnumber;
    for(rownumber=0;rownumber<3;rownumber++)
    {
        for(colnumber=0;colnumber<3;colnumber++)
        {
            board[rownumber][colnumber]='X'; // <--- Problem here
            if(checkwin('X')==1)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            board[rownumber][colnumber]=' ';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You are actually overwriting current position of your board with an `'X'`, without checking if there already was a symbol there before! So you are essentially overwriting your board with `'X'`es, checking if the X-player won and if not "resetting" to empty space `' '`!

You can fix this by inserting a check before your write like this:

```
if (board[rownumber][colnumber] == ' ')
{
    board[rownumber][colnumber]='X';
    ...
```

Comment: Oh!!!! that blank part was part of my psuedo-code! Thanks!! It looks like that part was the problem in my canwin and canblock functions. Thanks man!

Comment: Hm.. I just ran the code myself, but this didn't solve the problem, what about you?

Comment: Ah, I think you have the exact same problem in your `canblock()` function. This seemed to fix the code for me at least. Should be it.

Comment: yeah and it seems i forgot to put clear(); and displayboard(); during the if(checkwin()==1) so that it displays the final board during the win